# How to have special styles for a certain element inside a selector CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to add a dark mode function to my site, and I am going to use element.classList.toggle('dark'), where my CSS file includes:

```
.dark,
.dark * {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

But by doing this, the `background-color` of an element with the class `middle` would turn to `#222` as well, even though I want it to `middle` to turn to cyan when dark mode is on.
Is there a way that I can specify special styles for certain elements, inside a single selector? I would like to have `middle`'s `background-color` to turn to cyan, while the `background-color` of other elements to turn to `#222`, using only `.dark`.

This has probably been asked before, but I didn't know how to word it. Thanks.

Comment: `.dark .middle {background-color: cyan !important}`

Comment: @Rojo Where should I place the .middle? When I do .dark, .dark * .middle or .dark, .middle, .dark *, the background of the background of the entire page goes cyan, not .middle.

Comment: You don't need commas, just one space.

Comment: @Rojo Sorry if I am misunderstanding you, but if I do .dark .dark * .middle or .dark .middle .dark*, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: It's just `.dark .middle {`

Comment: @Rojo, this my current code: .dark .middle{
  background-color: #222;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  background: cyan !important;
}, but it still doesn't do anything. Is there another solution?

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder can you show your script as well? when using the `*` selector in css it generally matches any type like html, body, div, p etc etc.

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder remove `background-color #222;` from that

Comment: Sorry for the extended discussion, but @Rojo, it still does not work, and I need #222 for background-color for the rest of the elements. My question is, how do you have special styles for certain elements in a selector?

Comment: Could you share a codepen with your CSS? HTML might not be required, but you can add it if you want.

Comment: @Rojo Here: https://codepen.io/Crypt1111/pen/GRrrmrv

Comment: Ok, ***add*** `.dark .middle { background-color: cyan !important; }` to the end of the full CSS.